# C++ - Is it possible to use class inheritance without the member initialization list (MIL)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initializer-list

I have just learned about classes in C++. I know that data members can be initialized by using the member initialization list syntax (MIL), but I think it is not very intuitive to use, and I think it is a very ugly way to assign data members.

Apparently class inheritance in C++ MUST be done through this MIL syntax. I do not understand the rationale behind this and googling did not give me answers. I am also unable to find any counter-example to this rule. Every example I saw online about inheritance requires the MIL.

So my question is: Is it possible to set up an inheritance without the MIL?

If the answer is yes, please explain how.
If the answer is no, please explain why not. (give the rationale behind mandating the MIL for inheritance)

Comment: It depends... if all your classes can be aggregate or list initialized you can omit constructors at all. But if you need to provide somewhere constructors inside your hierarchy, you have to use the initializer list. Uggly? Matter of taste! It is a clear concept which is nice.

Comment: Can you elaborate about provide somewhere constructors?

Comment: Somewhere in the hierarchy means: if you have classes A, B and C and A inherits B and so on and one of them has a constructor, you can't use any longer the list or aggregate initialization.

Comment: BTW: Instead of waiting for explanation, simply try it out. Your compiler is the best friend to find out what is allowed and what is not. It is not a rule that everything which compiles is correct, but as a beginner it makes a lot of fun to try the things you read. Take you beginner book and lets go!

Comment: Any examples? I do not know what is aggregate. Also, what is a providing constructor?

Comment: I know that you did not know it. But we all can't copy all the primers book content here. Start reading your self. If you pick up `aggregate initialization` or `list initialization` here in the comments or answers, try to find out what it means your self! I can provide the links to the corresponding pages in the web... but you have to learn how to learn! "Providing a constructor" means that you write one. In taht case you provided it :-)

Comment: "Apparently class inheritance in C++ MUST be done through this MIL syntax." Please don't just tell us "apparently". If you reasonably believe this, then it must either be because someone told you (in which case you should cite it), or because you tried to test it (in which case you should show the code).

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in general. If the base class has a default constructor, you can omit its initializer in the constructor of the derived class if that is appropriate. Typically though, you will want to invoke a specific constructor, and the member initializer list is the place to do that.

The reason for this is the design of the language: all "direct subobjects" of a class, meaning the base class objects and non-static data members it introduces, are actually initialized even before the body of its constructor is entered. Explicit member initializers must be given for subobjects that cannot be default-initialized, otherwise the program is ill-formed (must be rejected by compilers). For further reference, see for example cppreference on [constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

In practice this means that, while a constructor can perform additional work after initialization, constructors with empty bodies are fairly common in C++, but ones with empty member initializer lists are not.